# Why it is "Task due date" and "Company name" but not "Task's due date" and "Company's name"?

Tags: possessives

When one should add `'s` and when not?

Examples:

- Task due date / Task's due date
- Company name / Company's name
- Form field / Form's field
- Customer service / Customers' service

Comment: When you use the above as headings, omit the possessive apostrophe. It's simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The versions without the genitive marker **'s** are very common. Nouns are used to modify other nouns. Wikipedia calls that use "noun adjunct":
[Wikipedia "noun adjunct"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

The version with the marker **'s** is used when the item identified isn't being viewed as a single unit. For example, you might say "This form's field for name is too short.". But to refer to a field on a form in general, you would say "form field".